# How can we have SortedList as a parameter in SortedDict in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sortedlist, sorteddictionary, sortedcontainers

I am trying to use **SortedList** from *sortedcontainers library* as a **parameter for SortedDict**. Even though the Initialization  `maps = SortedDict(SortedList())`  worked. I am Unable to insert any data into the SortedDict `maps`

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict, SortedList
maps = SortedDict(SortedList)
maps[1] = [1,2]
```

I tried doing the above code but i got a `TypeError:Int object is not Iterable`
so i tried maps['a'] = [1,2] and it worked but I am unable to further add elements into `maps['a'] using .add() or .update() methods of SortedList`.

I am only able to do so using `.append()` method => `maps['a'].append(0)` **does work but it loses the functionality of SortedList** as I got `maps = {'a':[1,2,0]}` where list was unsorted.

So how can I get `maps = {1:[1,2,4], 2:[8,9], 3:[1,5,6]}` in this way.

I have also tried using `maps = SortedDict(lambda x:SortedList)` which worked for defaultdict, so I tried it here but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the *class* `SortedList` to the constructor of the `SortedDict`. What do you expect that to do?

The [documentation](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html#sortedcontainers.SortedDict.__init__) explains what it actually does:

> Optional key-function argument defines a callable that, like the key argument to the built-in `sorted` function, extracts a comparison key from each dictionary key. If no function is specified, the default compares the dictionary keys directly. The key-function argument must be provided as a positional argument and must come before all other arguments.

So when trying to insert an entry, `SortedDict` calls `SortedList(1)`. This throws an error because the `SortedList` constructor expects an iterable, but `1` is not iterable.

If you want a `SortedDict` whose values are `SortedList` objects, just create an empty `SortedDict` and put only `SortedList` objects into it:

```
maps = SortedDict()
maps[1] = SortedList([1, 2])
```

Comment: Is it trivially easy to use `mypy` or similar to ensure that `maps` _only_ gets populated with `SortedList`?

Comment: @Thomas well, thought of having a map that contains SortList as value just from declaring it and without the need to do that explicitly everytime. just like how we can use List as default value in defaultdict in python. Thankyou for clarifying my query.

Comment: And just like how you can use `list` as default value in `defaultdict`, there's nothing stopping you from doing `my_default_dict[1] = "some string that is not a list"`.